# Asigning value to property which returns never null

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property

```
public static List<int> intItems
{
    get { return _intItems ?? new List<int>(); }
    set { _intItems = value; }
}
private static List<int> _intItems;
```

which is relyable never null. But when I `Add` a value to it it doesn't work.

```
intItems.Add(1);
Console.WriteLine(intItems.First()); //indexoutofrangeexception
```

To make this work, I have to assign the value to the private field first to enable a reference access:

```
public static List<int> intItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_intItems == null)
        {
            _intItems = new List<int>();
        }
        return _intItems;
    }
    set { _intItems = value; }
}
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way then a property with 12 lines of code? I have multiple of this kind.

Comment: @Rango I know and I also found a solution but it should be less code - or even a different Approach. Requirement is a `List<int>` which never returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to canton7's answer you can check for `null` on `set`:

```
private static List<int> _intItems = new List<int>();

public static List<int> intItems {
  get { return _intItems; }
  set { _intItems = value ?? new List<int>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal pattern for a lazy-loaded property is:

```
private static List<int> _intItems;
public static List<int> IntItems
{
    get => _intItems ?? (_intItems = new List<int>());
    set => _intItems = value;
}
```

If your requirement is to *stop* people from setting the property to null, while still allowing people to set it, the normal approach is to throw an exception:

```
private static List<int> _intItems = new List<int>();
public static List<int> IntItems
{
    get => _intItems;
    set => _intItems = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

However, if your requirement is just that your property never returns null, then why not do this:

```
public static List<int> IntItems { get; } = new List<int>();
```

Comment: the second Approach disables `IntItems  = GetIntegers(foo);`

Comment: Yes it does. That might or might not be what you want - you just asked for a "a property which is relyable never null", so it's hard to know what your actual needs are. That's why I posted the more accurate version first. Remember that you can do `IntItems.AddRange(GetIntegers(foo))`.